# how to create app shortcut on home screen on Android phones on installation

Tags: java, android

I have created an android application , which works fine
but now i want to add a feature that on installation the application should create a shortcut on home screen

please suggest 
i don't want the complete code work 
simple steps would be enough

Comment: http://codinggeekorg.wordpress.com/2011/01/02/android-how-to-add-home-screen-shortcuts-to-your-app/#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First declare that your application is using the INSTALL_SHORTCUT permission in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />



    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
    shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.example.androidapp", "SampleIntent");
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("someParameter", "HelloWorld");

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Name");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.icon));

    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

Comment: this cod part goes in the launcher activity ??

Answer (score 3):

in your manifest..

```
<activity android:name=".ShortCutActivity" android:label="@string/shortcut_label">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in the activity that receives the intent, you create an intent for your shortcut and return it as the activity result.

```
// create shortcut if requested
ShortcutIconResource icon =
    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);

Intent intent = new Intent();

Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityToLaunch.class);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, someNickname());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested Try it:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); shortcutIntent.setClassName(this, this.getClass().getName());

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "hello");
Parcelable iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);

intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);
getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Good Luck...