# created shortcut icon dissapears after reboot

Tags: java, android, shortcut

I have the ability to create extra shortcuts on the homescreen that deeplinks a user into my app.
([how to create app shortcut on home screen on Android phones on installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240194/how-to-create-app-shortcut-on-home-screen-on-android-phones-on-installation)) similar implementation

My code:

```
Intent addIntent = new Intent();
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, playlist.getTitle());
addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
if(combinedBitmap != null) {
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, combinedBitmap);
} else {
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, waveIcon);
}

addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

What happens is, on some devices on lollipop, after I restart the phone, the shortcut icon and name defaults to my app icon and name... Deeplink in my app still works.

Is there any way the shortcut icon and name stay after a reboot?

Comment: make sure application should not be installed in sd card

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi there is no sd card installed in the devices where it occurs

Comment: from this link http://www.technipages.com/android-icons-disappear-from-home-screen